# Compare Excel column and SQL database field before importing Excel file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, import

I want to compare name of columns of an Excel file with name of fields of a table in SQL database while importing data from Excel file. And then I can map my database filed name with Excel file column name.

Comment: Can you show us what have tried so far, it will help us to help you ;).

Comment: i have tried this [code]-http://blog.shuasolutions.com/2008/10/mapping-and-importing-excel-files-to-a-database-using-sqlbulkcopy/#more-40